# convert application.yml file to application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, application.properties

I have my application.yml file as below. How to convert it to application.properties
I am trying it but how can i write multiple properties in same file. Its giving me duplicate kery error.

```
 ---
  spring:
    profiles: peer1
  eureka:
     instance:
        hostname: peer1
     client:
        serviceUrl:
           defaultZone: http://peer2/eureka/

 ---
 spring:
    profiles: peer2
 eureka:
    instance:
      hostname: peer2
    client:
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://peer1/eureka/
```

Comment: The closest thing you can do is having an array of elements.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. You should clarify that, or you won't get any high-quality answers.

Answer (score 6):

IntelliJ and other IDEs provide plugins for the same.

For eg- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13804-convert-yaml-and-properties-file

Install the plugin, right click on your yaml or properties file and choose - "**Convert yaml and properties file**".

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot 2.4, there's the possibility to use the switch `spring.config.activate.on-profile` for this purpose, everything defined after `spring.config.activate.on-profile=myprofile` will only be set when the active profile is set to `myprofile`. In the given example, you would do as follows:

```
#-- Peer1 Config
spring.config.activate.on-profile=peer1
eureka.instance.hostname=peer1
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://peer2/eureka/
#-- Peer2 Config
spring.config.activate.on-profile=peer2
eureka.instance.hostname=peer2
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://peer1/eureka/
```

See https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

to do it manually:

```
spring:
    profiles: peer1
  eureka:
     instance:
        hostname: peer1
     client:
        serviceUrl:
           defaultZone: http://peer2/eureka/
```

will be like this:

```
spring.profiles=peer1
spring.eureka.instance.hostname=peer1
spring.eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://peer2/eureka/
```

Answer (score 0):

When using properties file, you cannot have multiple "sections" per profile in the same file, this is a feature available only with Yaml.
You will have to create several properties file, one per profile, as described here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment

> To do the same thing with properties files, you can use application-${profile}.properties to specify profile-specific values

You will have one main application.properties file containing common values, and then one application-${profile}.properties file per profile containing values that are environment/profile dependent.

Finally, you will have to set the active profile either as a System property when running the application, or directly in your main application.properties file, as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create differents files, example:

- application-dev.properties
- application-prod.properties
- application-test.properties

And then you deffine your active profile in the *application.properties* with:

```
 spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: but i need to run all instances together. These profiles are my eureka instances and i need to make cluster of them and run together. so how can i make one of them active at one time.

Comment: you can have several actives profiles : just provide the list with coma separated , e.g.:    `-Dspring.profiles.active=peer1,peer2`

Comment: If you are running multiple Eureka instances and want to access them interchangeably, then you should probably run a load balancer (like nginx) and point your app to that, or you should define a property which contains a list of URLs. The way you are trying to do it right now, it won't work as a yaml or as a properties file.

Comment: Oh wait, are you trying to follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/swlh/spring-cloud-high-availability-for-eureka-b5b7abcefb32 or something similar? If so: You do NOT "need to run all instances together". You need to have multiple profiles, and multiple containers, and in every container, exactly ONE of the profiles is active.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

The IntelliJ plugin works fine for "trivial" cases.

I had a more complex case.

The online tool below did it correctly:

https://env.simplestep.ca/

The "text" of the site above is:

"Environment Variable Generator
for Spring Boot apps" (in case the website dies in the future)

Example of my complex case:

```
things:
  combinations:
    - nameOf: favoriteColor
      valueOfValue: green
    - nameOfName: favoritePlanet
      valueOfValue: Mars
```

result from simplestep.ca

```
THINGS_COMBINATIONS_0_NAMEOF=favoriteColor
THINGS_COMBINATIONS_0_VALUEOFVALUE=green
THINGS_COMBINATIONS_1_NAMEOFNAME=favoritePlanet
THINGS_COMBINATIONS_1_VALUEOFVALUE=Mars
```

and this matches the spring documentation for "complex" types.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.merging-complex-types

below is code snipplets from the docs.spring.io link above.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("my")
public class MyProperties {

    private final List<MyPojo> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<MyPojo> getList() {
        return this.list;
    }

}
```

yaml

```
my:
  list:
  - name: "my name"
    description: "my description"
```

application.properties

```
my.list[0].name=my name
my.list[0].description=my description
```